# Spring cloud gateway custom AbstractGatewayFilterFactory Filter Error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using Spring Boot 3.2.0 and java 17.

I'm creating dynamic routes using Spring Cloud gateway and adding custom filter (`AbstractGatewayFilterFactory`) to check JWT authentication. Because I create routes dynamically (`RouteDefinitionRepository`) and not all my routes request authentication. When I call one route that required authentication, its returns with 401.

but when I observed the TRACE log it says my authentication was successful and suddenly its goes to `.switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {` method. and return 401 error.

WebFluxSecurity FilterChain

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
             .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                .pathMatchers("/route-management/**", "/api/**").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                    .jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtDecoder(jwtDecoder()))
                    .authenticationFailureHandler(serverAuthenticationFailureHandler()) // Handle authentication failures
                )
            
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .build();
}
```

DatabaseRouteDefinitionRepository - Where I get routes from Database and apply filters and my CustomAuthFiler.

```
public class DatabaseRouteDefinitionRepository implements RouteDefinitionRepository {

@Autowired
private GatewayRouteRepository gatewayRouteRepository;

@Autowired
private RouteDefinitionWriter routeDefinitionWriter;

@Override
public Flux<RouteDefinition> getRouteDefinitions() {
    List<GatewayRoute> routes = gatewayRouteRepository.findAll();
    List<RouteDefinition> routeDefinitions = routes.stream()
            .filter(gatewayRoute -> !gatewayRoute.isEditMode())
            .map(this::mapToRouteDefinition)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return Flux.fromIterable(routeDefinitions);
}

private RouteDefinition mapToRouteDefinition(GatewayRoute gatewayRoute) {
    RouteDefinition routeDefinition = new RouteDefinition();
    routeDefinition.setId(gatewayRoute.getRouteName());
    routeDefinition.setUri(URI.create(gatewayRoute.getUri()));
    // Add more configuration here, such as predicates, filters, etc.
    // Convert string representation of predicates and filters to actual objects

    // Set up predicates
    List<PredicateDefinition> predicateDefinitions = parsePredicates(gatewayRoute.getPredicates());
    routeDefinition.setPredicates(predicateDefinitions);

    // Set up filters
    List<FilterDefinition> filterDefinitions = parseFilters(gatewayRoute);
    routeDefinition.setFilters(filterDefinitions);

    return routeDefinition;
}

// Implement save and delete methods if needed
@Override
public Mono<Void> save(Mono<RouteDefinition> route) {
    return Mono.empty();
}

@Override
public Mono<Void> delete(Mono<String> routeId) {
    return Mono.empty();
}

private List<PredicateDefinition> parsePredicates(String predicates) {
    // Assuming predicates are comma-separated
    return Arrays.stream(predicates.split(","))
            .map(String::trim)
            .filter(predicate -> !predicate.isEmpty())
            .map(predicate -> new PredicateDefinition(predicate))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private List<FilterDefinition> parseFilters(GatewayRoute route) {

    List<FilterDefinition> filterList  = new ArrayList<>();

    for (GatewayRouteFilter gwf : route.getRouteFilters()) {
        FilterDefinition f = new FilterDefinition();
        f.setName(gwf.getFilterName());
        System.out.println("Filter : " + gwf.getFilterName());
        for(KeyValue kv : gwf.getData()) {
            f.addArg(kv.getFilterKey(), kv.getFilterValue());
            System.out.println("data : " + kv.getFilterKey() + " - " + kv.getFilterValue());
        }
        filterList.add(f);
    }
    
    if(route.isProtectedRoute()) {
        //apply authentication dynamically
        FilterDefinition authFiler = new FilterDefinition();
        authFiler.setName("CustomAuthFilter");
        
        authFiler.addArg("message", "Hello from filer config!");

        filterList.add(authFiler);
    }
    

    return filterList;

}

public Mono<RouteDefinition> getRouteDefinitionById(String routeId) {
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(mapToRouteDefinition(gatewayRouteRepository.findByRouteName(routeId)));
} }
```

Custom Auth Filter

```
public class CustomAuthFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<CustomAuthFilter.Config> {

private final ReactiveJwtCustomDecoder jwtDecoder;

public CustomAuthFilter(ReactiveJwtCustomDecoder jwtDecoder) {
    super(Config.class);
    this.jwtDecoder = jwtDecoder;
}

public static class Config {
    
    private String message;
    
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
        return extractJwtToken(exchange)
            .flatMap(this::validateJwtToken)
            .flatMap(jwt -> {
                // JWT token is valid
                log.info("Token is valid for request: {}", exchange.getRequest().getPath());
                return chain.filter(exchange); // Continue with the filter chain
            })
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
                
                // JWT token is invalid or not present
                log.info("JWT token is invalid or not present for request: {}", exchange.getRequest().getPath());
                exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
            }));
    };
}

private Mono<String> extractJwtToken(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    String token = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    log.info("Token : " + token);
    if (token != null && token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        return Mono.just(token.substring(7)); // Remove "Bearer " prefix
    }
    return Mono.empty(); // No token found
}

private Mono<Jwt> validateJwtToken(String token) {
    log.info("Validating token.. : {}",token);
    return jwtDecoder.decode(token); // Decode and validate the JWT token
}
```

Trace Log

```
2023-12-14T01:20:24.989+08:00 TRACE 24216 --- [     parallel-7] o.s.c.g.f.WeightCalculatorWebFilter      : Weights attr: {}
2023-12-14T01:20:24.989+08:00 TRACE 24216 --- [     parallel-7] o.s.c.g.h.p.PathRoutePredicateFactory    : Pattern "/api/bee/**" matches against value "/api/bee"
2023-12-14T01:20:24.989+08:00 DEBUG 24216 --- [     parallel-7] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route matched: route-1
2023-12-14T01:20:24.989+08:00 DEBUG 24216 --- [     parallel-7] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET http://localhost:9999/api/bee] to Route{id='route-1', uri=https://sittest.free.beeceptor.com:443, order=0, predicate=Paths: [/api/bee/**], match trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[sg.edu.singaporetech.cit.apigw.filters.CustomAuthFilter$$Lambda$1624/0x0000022283aa1bf0@322b7d2c, order = 1]], metadata={}}
2023-12-14T01:20:24.989+08:00 DEBUG 24216 --- [     parallel-7] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : [3c50e85d-20] Mapped to org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@53115ee0
2023-12-14T01:20:24.989+08:00 DEBUG 24216 --- [     parallel-7] o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted gatewayFilterFactories: [[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RemoveCachedBodyFilter@7108b12d}, order = -2147483648], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@664c411d}, order = -2147482648], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@4b094115}, order = -1], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@6dde03ce}, order = 0], [sg.edu.singaporetech.cit.apigw.filters.CustomAuthFilter$$Lambda$1624/0x0000022283aa1bf0@322b7d2c, order = 1], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@717b4de2}, order = 10000], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayNoLoadBalancerClientAutoConfiguration$NoLoadBalancerClientFilter@316987c4}, order = 10150], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@670e6fa3}, order = 2147483646], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@73ac7716}, order = 2147483647], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@16a4e4c9}, order = 2147483647]]
2023-12-14T01:20:24.989+08:00  INFO 24216 --- [     parallel-7] s.e.s.c.apigw.filters.CustomAuthFilter   : Token : Bearer **TOKEN**
2023-12-14T01:20:24.989+08:00  INFO 24216 --- [     parallel-7] s.e.s.c.apigw.filters.CustomAuthFilter   : Validating token.. : **TOKEN**
2023-12-14T01:20:24.998+08:00  INFO 24216 --- [     parallel-7] s.e.s.c.apigw.filters.CustomAuthFilter   : Token is valid for request: /api/bee
2023-12-14T01:20:24.998+08:00 TRACE 24216 --- [     parallel-7] o.s.c.g.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter   : RouteToRequestUrlFilter start
2023-12-14T01:20:24.999+08:00 TRACE 24216 --- [ctor-http-nio-7] o.s.c.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter  : outbound route: cff37c87, inbound: [3c50e85d-20] 
2023-12-14T01:20:25.183+08:00  INFO 24216 --- [ctor-http-nio-7] s.e.s.c.apigw.filters.CustomAuthFilter   : JWT token is invalid or not present for request: /api/bee
2023-12-14T01:20:25.184+08:00 TRACE 24216 --- [ctor-http-nio-7] o.s.c.g.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter  : NettyWriteResponseFilter start inbound: cff37c87, outbound: [3c50e85d-20]
```

In the above trace log you can see, CustomAuthFilter goes to `.switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {` event its successfully execute the `return chain.filter(exchange);`

Approch 1

After some research I found below approach and this working fine. But Spring doesn't recommend `.block()` in reactive application such as one built with Spring WebFlux. so I cannot use `.block()`

```
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
        try {
            String token = extractJwtToken(exchange).block(); // This will block until the token is extracted

            if (token != null) {
                try {
                    Jwt jwt = validateJwtToken(token).block(); // This will block until the token is validated

                    if (jwt != null) {
                        // JWT token is valid
                        log.info("Token is valid for request: {}", exchange.getRequest().getPath());
                        return chain.filter(exchange); // Continue with the filter chain
                    } else {
                        // JWT token is invalid
                        log.info("JWT token is invalid for request: {}", exchange.getRequest().getPath());
                        exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                        return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Handle validation errors
                    log.error("Error during token validation: {}", e.getMessage());
                    exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                    return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
                }
            } else {
                // JWT token is not present
                log.info("JWT token is not present for request: {}", exchange.getRequest().getPath());
                exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle errors in token extraction
            log.error("Error extracting token: {}", e.getMessage());
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
        }
    };
```

Is anyone know how do I fix this issue or is there any better approch?
Thanks in advance!